# sql query for alphanumeric ID in hex

Tags: sql, sql-server, hex, alphanumeric

I want to be able to differentiate between a string that is alphnumeric and a string that is in hex format.

My current query is:

```
<columnName> LIKE '?_____=' + REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]',16)
```

I found this method of searching for hex ID's online and I thought it was working. However after getting a significantly larger sample size I can see a high false positive rate in my results. The problem is that this gives me all the results I do want but it also gives me a bunch of results I dont care about. For example:

I want to see:

```
<url>.php?mains=d7ad916d1c0396ff
```

but i dont want to see:

```
<url>.php?mblID=2007012422060265
```

The difference between the 2 strings is that the 16 characters at the end that i want to collect are all numeric and not a hex ID. What are some ways you guys use to limit the results to hex ID only? Thanks in advnace.

**UPDATE:**
Juergen brought up a good point,  the second number could be a hex value to. Not all hex numbers contain [a-F]. I would like to rephrase the question to state that I am looking for an ID with both letters and numbers in it, not just numbers.

Comment: But the second number could be a hex value to. Not all hex numbers contain [a-F]

Comment: @juergend That is a good point. I will rephrase the question to state I am looking for an ID with both letters and numbers in it, not just numbers.

Comment: You can't possibly determine if a string represents hex or decimal without any extra information being stored about what base it is. If you have a string containing `12345678`, say, how do you know if that is decimal or hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is just to add a separate clause for that restriction:

```
    <columnName> LIKE '?_____=' + REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]',16)
AND <columnName> NOT LIKE '?_____=' + REPLICATE('[0-9]',16)
```

Comment: Great! i didn't even think to do that. Thank you! i will mark this as my answer in 5-8 minutes when stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: IF you need to avoid every possible pitfall, use REPLICATE('[0-9ABCDEFabcdef]',16) and apply a COLLATE clause to the LIKE expression that specifies an accent-sensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly simple to determine if a string contains only numbers...

Setting up a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (Data char(32)  not null)

INSERT #Temp
  values ('<url>.php?mains=d7ad916d1c0396ff')
        ,('<url>.php?mblID=2007012422060265 ')
```

Write a query:

```
SELECT
   right(Data, 16)             StringToCheck
  ,isnumeric(right(Data, 16))  IsNumeric
 from #Temp
```

Get results:

```
StringToCheck   IsNumeric
d7ad916d1c0396ff    0
2007012422060265    1
```

So, if the IsNumeric function returns 0, it could be a hex string.

This makes several assumptions:

- The rightmost 16 characters are what you want to check
- You only ever hit 16 characters. I don't know when the string would get too long to check.
- A non-numeric character means hex. Any chance of "Q" or "~" being embedded in the string?

Comment: ISNUMERIC won't quite do it, because it accepts some strings that contain the letter E. For example, isnumeric('1234567890123E12') evaluates to 1.